# Need to create an SSIS Package for users to directly modify a table

Tags: user-controls, ssis

I need to allow a couple of users to modify a table in my database, preferably as part of an integrated package that then submits the changes into our live database.

Please allow me to explain further:

We have an automated import task from one database system into another, with data transformation on the way through.

As part of this task, various checks are run before the final import and any rows with incomplete or incorrect data are sent to a rejections table and deleted from the import table.

I now need to allow a couple of senior users that ability to view and correct the missing/incorrect entries from the rejection table, before re-staging it and submitting to the live database.
(Obviously, it will be re-checked before submission and re-rejected if it is still wrong).

Can anyone tell me what I need to do in SSIS to display the contents of a specific table (e.g. MyDatabase.dbo.Reject_Table) to the user running this package from their local PC (the package will, of course, be located on the server).

Then they need the ability to modify the contents of the table - Either 1 row at a time or en-masse.  Not bothered which).

When that is done, they hit a "Continue" or "Next" type button, which then continues to run the remainder of the package, which I am more than comfortable writing.

It is only the interactive stage(s) that I am struggling with and I would really appreciate some advice.

Thanks
Craig

Answer (score 2):

That is non-native functionality in SSIS.

You *can* write pretty much anything you want in a script task and that includes GUI components. (I once had a package play music). In your data flow, you would have a Script Component that edits each row passing through the component.

### Why this is a bad idea

Suitability - This isn't really what SSIS is for. The biggest challenge you'll run into is the data flow is tightly bound to the shape of the data. The reject table for Customer is probably different than the reject table for Phone.

Cost - How are you going to allow those senior users to run SSIS packages? If the answer involves installing SSIS on their machines, you are looking a production license for SQL Server. That's 8k to 23k ish per socket for SQL Server 2005-2008R2 and something insane per *core* for SQL Server 2012+.

### What is a better approach

As always, I would decompose the problem into smaller tasks until I can solve it. I'd make 2 problem statements

1. As a data steward, I need the ability to correct (edit) incomplete data so that data can be imported into our application.
2. As an X, I need the ability to import (workflow) corrected rejected data so that we can properly bill our customers (or whatever the reason is).

Editing data. I'd make a basic web page or thick client app to provide edit capability. A [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0ywh3cz.aspx) would be one way of doing. Heck, you could forgo custom development and just slap an Access front end to the tables and let them edit the data through that.

Import corrected data. This is where I'd use SSIS but possibly not exclusively. I'd probably look at adding a column to all the reject tables that indicates whether it's ready for reprocessing. For each reject table, I'd have a package that looks for any rows flagged as ready. I'd probably use a [Delete first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503959/ssis-foreach-through-a-table-insert-into-another-and-delete-the-source-row/15508174#15508174) pattern to remove the flagged data and either insert it into the production tables or route it back into the reject table for further fixing. The mechanism for launching the packages could be whatever makes sense. Since I'm lazy,

1. I'd have a SQL Agent job that runs the packages and
2. Create a stored proc which can start that job
3. Grant security on that stored proc to the data stewards
4. Provide the stewards a big red button that says `Import` How that's physically implemented would depend on how you solved the edit question.

Comment: Thanks mate.  

Great answer.  

I'll look in to them using a web page to do this, as I don't really want to have to configure Access as well (they don't use it at the moment, and I'm not sure that they are familiar with it).  Any pointers on the web route? (Things to avoid, etc.)